# Adding photos to iPhone from Mac using image capture

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, photos, image-capture

Does anyone know of a way that I can put photos on my iPhone using image capture?

Comment: Fascinating question - the data flow is clearly designed to go the other way, but sometimes you can find hidden settings or tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the pictures to your photostream in Photos.They will appear on your phone if you have Photo streaming turned on.

Comment: Actually, it needs to be using image capture because it bypasses Live Photos and separates it into a photo and a video. I'm trying to play with the framework by making fake Live Photos

Comment: Hmm I use image Capture to connect to a scanner. It captures in picture formats not video. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Image capture works for all video formats as well

Comment: Interesting but your question was how to put photos on your phone not video. I just dragged a photo to Photos and it appears on my phone. Try that with your video.

Comment: But Photos carries the 6s Live Photo metadata. I need to bypass that which is why I'm using image capture